# MySQL 5.5 errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-5.5

There are plenty of questions regarding this error but I can't seem to find any similar scenario to what I have.

My 1st table (users):

[image]

My 2nd table (colleges):

[image]

**I am trying to alter 1st table and add a foreign key that references `id` of a 2nd table**:

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (collegelinkId)
REFERENCES databaseName.colleges (id);
```

Which fails with error `(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")`.

The only parameter that is different between these two tables is `auto_increment`. However, I can not add auto_increment to my users table `collegelinkId` column since its `id` is already set to auto_increment.

Comment: I'm not sure that your screen capture is reflective of reality, and the two columns are not exactly the same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the columns are of the same type, it's worth to check the engine type as @Tim Biegeleisen suggested.

Changing engine type fixed the issue.

```
ALTER TABLE users
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1):

We would expect to see this error if the types of the primary and foreign key did not match exactly.  While both appear to be integer with a width of 1, my guess here is that one of the `INT` columns in the key relationship is unsigned, while the other is signed.  A possible fix would be to make both columns unsigned:

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY collegelinkId INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE college MODIFY id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

**Edit:**

I was wrong, as evidenced by your latest comments under my answer.  Another possibility is that you created your two tables using different database engines.  For example, if you created `users` using InnoDB, but `college` using MyISAM, you could still get this error.  To fix this, change the engine(s) on the tables to the same type.

Note that yet another possibility would be that the two columns had different collations.  But, that's really a moot point here, since both columns are numeric, not text.

Comment: currently both college's `id` and users's `collegelinkId` are signed

Comment: Then it doesn't make any sense why you are getting this error.  They are number columns, so collation is out as possible explanation.  The only thing which might explain it is that you created the `users` and `college` table using different engines.

Comment: yes, so as I mentioned the only thing that is different is `auto_increment`. what do you mean by 'created using different engines'?

Comment: E.g. you created one table with MyISAM and the other with InnoDB.  I recommend that you double check the column definitions/types.

Comment: the column definitions/types are the same. however, I did check the engine type which was indeed different. thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

- Verify that the datatypes match (except for `PRIMARY KEY`).
- Verify that both tables are `ENGINE=InnoDB`.

Even after that, error 150 can still occur.  3 ways around it:

- Disable FKs while creating the tables, then re-enable.
- `CREATE TABLEs` without FKs, then `ALTER ... ADD ... FKs`
- Be sure the do the `CREATEs` in just the right order.

A side note:  In `INT(2)`, the `(2)` is irrelevant.  All `INTs` are 4 bytes.