# SQLException while adding new fields to existing @Entity (jpa)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, mariadb

I had a model that for example looks like this:

```
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Map;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class MyTable {

    @Id
    long myId;

    @NotNull
    String myField_1;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @NonNull
    Map<Integer, BigDecimal> myField_2;
}
```

I ran it on the server, the app (a Spring Boot application) worked with this table for a while and I decided that I need another field:

```
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @NonNull
    Map<Integer, BigDecimal> myAdditionalField;
```

But when I run the app on the server again I get such exceptions:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table my_table_my_additional_field add constraint FK35gbk1v4oaclmxu6onjiopln0 foreign key (my_table_my_id) references my_table (my_id)" via JDBC Statement
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't create table `my_database_name`.`#sql-7f7_4531` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Why does it happening and how to add new fields to my entity? I have a property `jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update`. The funniest part is that the field and it's "map collection" are added to the db correctly, it's just there is this strange constraint error for this new field

Comment: For a more predictable way to update your tables, consider using Flyway (https://rieckpil.de/howto-best-practices-for-flyway-and-hibernate-with-spring-boot/). With Flyway you have the full control of your schema migrations as with `jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update` you give away control to Hibernate which might do something you do not intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for that error message.

Here's one answer that lists some options:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56976063/1766831